# How prove this there exist positive integer sets $A$ such $|A+A|>|A-A|$

Tags: number-theory, inequality

let positive integer $n\ge 8$ is given, show that: there exist sets $A$ with the set of is positive integer.such $|A|=n$,and such
$$|A+A|>|A-A|$$
where 
$$A-A=\{a-b|a\in A,b\in A\},A+A=\{a+b|a\in A,b\in A\}$$

This problem seem like this [How prove this set inequality $|B|\ge 2|A|^2-1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/709530/how-prove-this-set-inequality-b-ge-2a2-1?rq=1)

I search some paper, Found this problem background is :

The following are called Minkowski sum and difference of sets:

$$A-A=\{a-b|a\in A,b\in A\},A+A=\{a+b|a\in A,b\in A\}$$

The other notation is the cardinality $ |X|$ of a set $ X$

But I can't prove this, maybe $n\ge 8$ is useful

Comment: Not every question involving sets has to do with set theory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will find much discussion of this question if you type "more sums than differences" into the web. For example, here's a [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0608131) by Greg Martin and Kevin O'Bryant that should answer your question, and more.

Comment: Nice.Thank you very much!+1